# Hiding address bar on iOS7 destroys the site

Tags: javascript, ios7.1

I'm coding a responsive magazine with JavaScript and I added the new feature for hiding the address bar. Sadly, it totally destroys the site, and oddly enough, the magazine looks like 300% bigger.

I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
    width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious- is there something to add/delete in my code?

And I add this new line :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui">
```

Comment: When asking such questions you should make clear what you changed. Did you add all those lines or was e.g. the first line already in your page, and adding the following 3 lines broke your layout?

Comment: What does "destroys the site" mean? It's an extremely vague problem description; you sound like you're saying the whole site is gone and you have to rebuild it.

Comment: Maybe you should add `, minimal-ui` to the end of the "viewport" `<meta>` tag you already have.